# .net mvc send json with mixed types from controller

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc

So I have this JsonResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getJsonInvoicesClient(int id_client)
{
    var a = db.invoices
        .Where(x => x.id_client == id_client)
        .ToList();
    return Json(a);
}
```

and in jquery I receive a list of invoice objects.
Now I need to add the client data to the json, so I get it from the db with something like:

```
    var c = db.clients.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == id_client);
```

But how can I add this client object to the json... so that in jquery I receive a list or similar with just 2 items: the client object, and the list of invoice objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use anonymous type:

```
var invoices = db.invoices
    .Where(x => x.id_client == id_client)
    .ToList();
var clinet = db.clients.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == id_client);
return Json(new
{
    clinet,
    invoices
});
```